# Wordpress search form not displaying results as it should be

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, custom-post-type

I am using a form to search from 2 custom post types i.e   `job_listing` & `product` . It works fine if user enters  something in input field but if he doesn't enters anything then the search page open where the   post type `post` are displayed
[image]

rather it should have displayed results from post type  `job_listing` or `product` depending upon the select field selected

Code for the form is :

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">                  
  <div class="input-box">
     <input name="s" id="s" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What you are looking for...">
  </div>

  <div class="selection-box">
      <select name="post_type" id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control">
          <option value="job_listing">Listing</option>
          <option value="product">Shop</option>                                                
       </select>                      
  </div>

  <div class="search-btn">
       <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="search">
  </div>
</form>
```

what will I have to do to make it work the way I want.

Comment: I think that if your theme is a third party theme, you should ask the theme developer for this. As far as I can understand your issue, it's theme-dependent.

Comment: @Stratboy  Thanks for your time & help.Actually i am using  child theme of listify theme . And I am pretty much sure those guys are not going to help on this matter .. I will test the code with  some default theme or custom theme to see if it works ..

Comment: To come back to your original question: do you mean that if one doesn't write anything on the search field AND click the search button, then the resulting page will be the posts archive?

Comment: its still a search page but the results only have posts

Comment: So you want the posts not to be searchable at all?

Comment: @Stratboy sry fr the late reply ..ya exactly--  posts not to be searchable at all for this search form only   ,, because you see i am only giving them option to select from 2 custo post types

Answer (score 0):

If you can do some code, you can use the all-purpose [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to alter the search query (there are examples on the official docs).

Or use a plugin like this (it lets you exclude posts from search, as well as search for custom metaboxes values and so on..): https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/.

Comment: then i guess it will change the results for all search query forms & not just this particular form... right??

Comment: Mmmm, I think yes, excuse me, I didn't think you had more than 1 search field...

If you've got different search forms that have to serach for different things, probably you have to code or hire a good developer. I don't know if there are suitable plugins for this, since it's a quite unusual use case. But maybe yes... Just take a look at the plugin directory and try out some.

Comment: P.s. anyway, if no plugins, I think the right path is still using pre_get_posts, but maybe adding a custom query var to read on the filter callback and to rely on to modify the main query.

Comment: Hiring another developer is not an option due to the cost of project , i guess i will try pre_get_posts...  if nothing works then i guess last method will to put the redirection .. for example if some body searches in custom post = job_listing without typing anything then result url is http://example.com/?s=&post_type=job_listing   ,   so i will redirect this to http://example.com/listings/  (archive page for job_listing custom post)  thanks for your help buddy